# #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-2002

I am working on a windows server 2012 and trying to get PHPMyAdmin working.  I cant get it to connect to the MySQL by root user or a non root user.  I have searched and searched all over google. everywhere I saw it said to set allowroot and change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the config.inc.php file. At first I could not find this file but then I read you have to change config.default.php to it and put it in the root folder.  I did that. and here is what I changed

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "127.0.0.1"
//already had the next one set
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true
```

I still cant get it to login from any user on MySQL, and I keep getting the error

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.
```

config.inc.php: http://u16626886.onlinehome-server.com/config.inc.zip

Testing PHP and MySQL: http://u16626886.onlinehome-server.com:801/test.php

I figured out the problem just need to solve it now.  If I put MySQL on the C: drive it works fine but if I put it on the D: drive, which is where I want it, PHP can not connect to it.  Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Is it fixed ? How did you fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
It may be Mysql service is not running, try to start Mysql service

Sometimes Mysql Service May Not Run..
 Try the following
   1. Remove/Unstall the service
            a) Start Cmd As Administrator
            b) Type Mysql --remove
   2. Restart Pc
   3. Install
        a) Start Cmd As Administrator
        b) Use Cd ../ To locate the path for Mysqld (For me it is in C:\xampp\mysql\bin)
        c)Type mysqld --Install
   4. Restart Pc
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solved my problem on mac.

-config.inc.php-

change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

and then,

-go to terminal -

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and then come back and reloaded page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2002 MySQL Socket error, we can resolve this quickly by executing following command

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql 
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Note: Above path is based on MAC, so you can change the path according to your OS

Answer (score -2):

Run SKYPE then using the menus do this:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'

Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

Comment: I have to ask what does skype have to do with this question?  Skype is not even installed on the server.

Comment: @Shredder2500 , Then check you have any other app like skype who holds port 443 or 80. go to their settings and choose appropriate options.

Comment: You might consider of rephrasing your answer in a way focusing the possible usage of a port being needed by MySQL ... but even then it would be a comment in my eyes.